# Can't seem to create a partition on free space from windows

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot, system-installation

So, I managed to free up some space from windows (100GB) to install ubuntu on, but every time I try to install it I get an input/output write error on my disk.
Also tried doing it manually with fdisk, which says

```
The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Syncing disks.
```

But when I check again with either fdisk or gparted, nothing happens. I doubt it is a hardware problem as I have read online, since windows seems to work perfectly on that disk. Any ideas what my problem might be? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a filesystem on the disk in or is it just unallocated space? Also, if there is a read-write error, have you checked the disk for errors?

Comment: can we see the partition table information before you change it and then again before you attempt to write it?   If for some reason the partition table was written but not re-read a reboot might help.